# Method not detected in model " undefined method `process_uri' "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, model, omniauth

Im trying to figure out why i cant get my method to be identified. Maybe im not seeing things clearly and made a little mistake that someone can catch? Here is my code and when i click on the button i get this error.

**User Model:** when `if auth.info.image.present?` gets passed the `process_uri` gets called but my method isn't identified.

```rails
def self.from_omniauth(auth)

 anonymous_username = "NewUser#{User.last.id + 1}"
 generated_password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]

  user = User.where(:email => auth.info.email, :username => anonymous_username).first


  if user
    return user
  else
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.confirmed_at = Time.now
      user.fullname = auth.info.name
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.username = anonymous_username
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = generated_password

    end

if auth.info.image.present?
   avatar_url = process_uri(auth.info.image)
   user.update_attribute(:avatar, URI.parse(avatar_url))
end

  end
end


private 

  def process_uri(uri)
    require 'open-uri'
    require 'open_uri_redirections'
    open(uri, :allow_redirections => :safe) do |r|
      r.base_uri.to_s
    end
  end
```

As you can see I have a private method underneath `def process_uri(uri)` .. even when i take out private this still isn't being noticed... thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the private method `process_uri` is an instance method, whereas `from_omniauth` is a class method. In the context of a class method, the `self` object that the method would be called on is the class, not the instance, so you get an undefined method error because there is no class method `process_uri`. You can either define `process_uri` as a class method, or you can make it public and call it on the object itself (e.g. `user.process_uri`).

Comment: Okay! so should i add `def self.process_uri(uri)` as my method instead??